# SQL CE 3.5 in VS2008 doesnt have char/varchar type. Only nchar/nvarchar

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I am trying to create a table in SQL CE 3.5 in Visual Studio 2008 on XP and it only has nchar/nvarchar for column types. *(in designer)*

The full version is 3.5.5386.0

According to this article the **CE 3.5 must support char and varchar** : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424(v=sql.105).aspx

Any ideas?

Comment: SQL Compact Edition (CE) 3.5 does not support varchar, only nvarchar.  I don't see a reference to varchar anywhere in that article you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL CE has been [Unicode-based for a long time now.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275635%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

> Not all data types in SQL Server are supported in SQL Server CE. For
>   example, non-Unicode text columns (varchar, char, text) and smallmoney
>   are not supported; although nvarchar, nchar, ntext, and money are
>   supported.

You must have misread the article that you're linking to. There is no mention of char/varchar only nchar/nvarchar. And you may find [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577209/why-doesnt-sql-server-ce-support-varchar) interesting.

Comment: you are right actually.. i am reading this article and there is nothing about varchar :) perhaps i mixed up two different articles in my mind... need holiday! :)